# How to work with big multiline strings in JSON with vscode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have a big json that has a lot of keys and a lot of values are long multiline string. Here is a sample simplified json:

```
{
    "key" : "line1\nline2\nline3"
}
```

I would like to use vscode to work with such json-s.

It is a huge pain to work with multiline string in json, I would like to edit the line `line1\nline2\nline3` as a text:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I've search vscode marketpalce but I haven't found any extension that solves this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There now seems to be an extension for this: [Multiline String Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chop-dbhi.multiline-string-editor). Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I've tried it and it works very well, but there is an issue. It does not work when there is "autosave" feature enabled. I had to disable "autosave" to use this extension.